# Runtime Update Filds in rich text editor DevExpress Asp.net Core

Tags: devexpress, rich-text-editor

I use rich text editor DevExpress in Asp.net Core
How can I put fields in the template file and update them Runtime.
by java Script or JQuery or...

Answer (score 0):

Please [submit your question](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ask) to DevExpress Support team. I am sure they will be happy to address this issue.